# Automate Notepad++ Macro

Tags: automation, macros, notepad++

I've created a Notepad++ Macro that I need to run at a set interval.

Is there a way to schedule running a macro - for example every 15 minutes?

Comment: What OS?  What are you trying to accomplish?  If you're on Windows, you can use Windows Task Scheduler.  If linux, use `cron`.

Comment: I am on Windows. How would I add running the macro to Windows Task Scheduler?

Comment: This should get you going: https://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-schedule-programs-run-automatically-windows-7.htm